# How to restrict access to api - Spring security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use spring security to secure our rest api. We are at a point where we have more than 200 resources currently and looks like it will grow further. Currently we are restricting the api access like the following

```
  /**
   * Configures the Http security
   * 
   * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users", "/user").hasRole("USER_CREATE")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/users").hasRole("USER_EDIT")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users", "/users/**","/users/count").hasRole("USER_VIEW")
          .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // configure custom exception handling for errors occuring in filters
    http.addFilterAfter(exceptionHandlerFilterBean(),
        CorsFilter.class);

    // configure custom JWT based security filter
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // disable page caching
    http.headers().cacheControl();
  }
```

But this has to be added for over 200+ resources the method will become big. I think this current implementation looks clumsy even though it does the work. So is there a better of dealing with this scenario?

Comment: are you saying you're going to have 600+ roles of type resourcename_CREATE, _EDIT and _VIEW?

Comment: @Plog yes something like that.